ngx extended-pdf-viewer Fails to Load viewer ftl in Production Deployment
I am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer in my Angular application to display PDF documents. The viewer works perfectly when I run the application locally. However, once I deploy the application to the server, the viewer starts throwing a bunch of errors which severely affect the app's performance.
Here are the specifics:
Network Requests
While inspecting the network requests in the browser's Developer Tools, I noticed that the following files are being requested:
locale.json
viewer.ftl
P311N_file_name
Of these, locale.json and P311N_file_name are fetched successfully. However, viewer.ftl consistently returns a 404 Not Found error in the deployed environment.
Observations
Local Environment:
URL: http://localhost:4200/assets/locale/en-US/viewer.ftl
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
The viewer works without any issues.
Deployed Environment:
URL: https://xyz.websites/assets/locale/en-US/viewer.ftl
Status Code: 404 Not Found
The viewer throws errors, leading to performance issues.
I suspect the problem might be related to differences in the file paths between the local and deployed environments, but I haven't been able to pinpoint a solution.

I had the same problem on my side.
If you are using IIS it could be that you'll need to change your web.config to allow .ftl files to be served.
I added these lines to the frontend web.config file
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ftl" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".properties" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>


Above answer from @BenGeeBee did not work for me. However I found solution under ngx-extended-pdf-viewer repo in GitHub comment.
My application is running .NET 8, so adding below to program.cs file fixed the issue.
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".ftl"] = "text/plain"; 

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});

